# I want to change where the cursor moves when editing html files when using pycharm

Tags: html, pycharm

When I am editing an html file in pycharm and the cursor is behind a tag
When I press the return key, the cursor goes to the previous indentation.
What setting should I change?
I would appreciate your help.

First:

```
<body>
    <h1>xxx</h1>|
                ↑ cursor
</body>
```

[Now]

```
<body>
    <h1>xxx</h1>
|
↑ cursor
</body>
```

[Ideal]

```
<body>
    <h1>xxx</h1>
    |
    ↑ cursor
</body>
```

I checked the following configuration items on pycharm, but there did not seem to be any applicable items.

settings > Editor > code style > HTML

Answer (score 0):

The indents work that way because there is a setting in PyCharm that prevents indents for children of specified nodes. To fix it, please do the following:

1. Navigate Settings > Editor > Code Style > HTML.
2. Open Other tab.
3. Find the option Do not indent children of.
4. Remove unnecessary tags.